# Windows Batch File - List files in a specified set of directories?

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch file that will:

1. Read a list of directories from a text file I specify.
2. Loop through those directories and list all of the files in each directory.

I can find instructions on how to read from a text file and I can find instructions on how to read file names in a directory, but I can't seem to get the two functions working together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
set "logfile=x:\path\filelist.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (folderlist.txt) do (
    cd /d "%%~i"
    dir /b /a-d >>"%logfile%"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to what I was looking for. Is it possible to write the output to one file instead of writing everything to a "filelist.txt" inside each directory?

Comment: `do dir "%%~i" /b /a-d >> "x:\path\filelist.txt"`  <--- That could be used to simplify the code.

Comment: Yes, thank you. At first was this in my mind: `for /f "delims=" %i in (test.txt) do @for %a in ("%~i\*") do @echo %~fa` but I didn't know, if paths were needed.